# How to display taxonomies in a WordPress custom post?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Newbie here. I was following a video tutorial displaying **custom taxonomies** in WordPress. In the video tutorial it was showing how to edit the file *single_product.php* which is the custom taxonomy that was used in the video as an example, this file was in the directory **wp-content/theme/current_theme**. But as I check my installation directory I don't see it anywhere. I have research the WordPress codex and was mentioned that sometimes the **custom post single.php** file is not available for all themes. And that the single.php file should just be used and modified instead.

Can someone help me how to modify the **single.php** file to display the taxonomies on each custom post I have? or maybe point me to good reference? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**A wordpress theme must have at least 2 files:**

- style.css
- index.php

All other files are optional. To understand which file is for which purpose, you can read [this article "Template Hierarchy"](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and look [this graphic](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png). It helped me a lot.

**To get taxonomies of a post**, you can use [`get_the_taxonomies()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_taxonomies).